# :first-letter selector doesn't work for link

Tags: css, pseudo-element

The `:first-letter` pseudo-element selector works perfectly for a `<p>` element but not for links. This, for instance, has no effect:

```
a:first-letter
{
    font-size:200%;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

Why? How can I make the first-letter style different for an `<a>` element

Answer (score 5):

According to the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-CSS2-20101207/selector.html#first-letter), the `:first-letter` pseudo-element only work for a block element, which `a` is not.

Oddly, `*:first-letter` caused the first letter to transform, at Chrome 14 and Firefox 3.6.23. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8W7FF/3/

Comment: Your jsfiddle demo "works" because the first O letter is not just `:first-letter` of `<a>` but also `:first-letter` of `<body>`. Nevertheless, +1, your answer looks correct.

Comment: I would imagine that is because * will include the `body` tag, which jsFiddle puts there automatically.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis Just to be more precise, it needn't to be jsfiddle what includes `<body>` into document; in HTML, `<body>` has optional both opening and closing tags. *Every* HTML document has its `body`, no matter if you explicitly add it into markup or not.

Comment: @duri Right.  Sorry if that may have been ambiguous.  Rather, I was trying to say that jsFiddle serves the content which has a body tag, not that the body tag must be explicitly marked as jsFiddle has done.

Comment: @RobW You've just proved that it really **is** because of `body`. The selector `body *` matches "any element inside `body`" == the `a` element. As `:first-letter` doesn't work on inline elements, the letter doesn't get capitalized. Try using `body:first-letter` and you'll see the letter gets capitalized because it is the first letter of `body`, even if it's a first letter of another element (`a` in this case).

Comment: why not change display property of "a" tag to block?

Answer (score 4):

Check the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#first-letter). As of now, `inline` elements are not supported by `::first-letter`:

> In CSS, the `::first-letter` pseudo-element applies to block-like containers such as `block`, `list-item`, `table-cell`, `table-caption`, and `inline-block` elements.
> *Note: A future version of this specification may allow this pseudo-element to apply to more display types.*
> https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#application-in-css

Thus, if you try to style the `::first-letter` of something that isn't a "block-like container", like an inline element, it won't work. This doesn't just apply to links; you'll also find that, by default, you can't style the `::first-letter` of a `span` either, as shown below:

```css
div::first-letter, span::first-letter, a::first-letter {
    font-size:200%;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm a div</div>
<span>I'm a span</span>
<a href="https://google.com">I'm an anchor</a>
```

A possible fix to this is to turn the element into a block container by, for instance, setting it to `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. Below is an example, using the former for the `span` and the latter for the `a`:

```css
div::first-letter, span::first-letter, a::first-letter {
    font-size:200%;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#8A2BE2;
}
span {
    display: block;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm a div</div>
<span>I'm a span</span>
<a href="https://google.com">I'm an anchor</a>
```

Comment: you can also apply ::first-letter to anchor wrapper element