# Wordpress Menu Dropcaps with Rootstheme and Twitter's Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Twitter Bootstrap 3 Wordpress [RootsTheme](http://www.rootstheme.com/).

1. How do I create Wordpress Dropcaps Primary Navigation Menu?

   [Wordpress Navigation Menu Dropcaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19cra.jpg)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example page on http://demo.rootstheme.com/ you could use `.navbar-nav > li > a:first-letter` as your selector (add this to your style.css file):

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:first-letter {
     color: green;
     font-size: 20px;
     /* your style */
  }
```

See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/ for information about the first-letter pseudo class. Read also: [css first-letter for link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984179/css-first-letter-for-link). first-letter only works for block level elements. The bootstrap css set the anchors in the nav to block display with:

```
    .nav > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        position: relative;
     }
```

[image: Drop Cap]