# Aligning character in a string that are different sizes with css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have an `<` that is part of a string `< ALL APPS` that is a different size than the other characters in the string. I am able to change its size using the `::first-character` selector. But the rest of the characters should appear in the center of the text like in the first image below.

.scss

```
.allapps {
  a {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
  }

  a::first-letter {
    font-size: 29px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 18px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
```

_nav.html.erb

```
<div class='well well-lg'>
  <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
    <li class='allapps bold'><%= link_to '< ALL APPS', list_apps_path %></li>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if @version_type == "test" %> pull-right">
      <%= link_to 'TEST', list_versions_path(params["app_id"], version_type: :test)%>
    </li>
    <li class="<%= 'active' if @version_type == "main"%> pull-right">
      <%= link_to 'MAIN', list_versions_path(params["app_id"], version_type: :main) %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

desired

[image]

actual

[image]

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) you could share?

Comment: `:first-letter` only applies to block level elements. You could be super unsemantic and say something like `<a href="#"><p>&lt;hello</p></a>`

Comment: @chad it still appears the same try that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nvrveo3s/

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984179/css-first-letter-for-link

Comment: @chad when I change the font-size it is not as pretty. Not sure if you can see my update on jsfiddle

Comment: That's just a font issue (you need a prettier font)-- not pertinent to this issue. And no, I can't see your update unless you update something and send a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set vertical placement of the “<” symbol. This is best done with relative positioning, since `vertical-align` has specialties and differences in implementations. You should wrap the “<” character in a `span` element for styling, since there is no guarantee that `:first-letter` matches a character that is not a letter (alphabetic); the specifications are vague, and implementations differ.

A simple pure HTML and CSS demo:

```css
.allapps {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.allapps .lt {
    font-size: 29px;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class=allapps><span class=lt>&lt;</span> ALL APPS</div>
```

The exact amount of displacement (the `top` value in the sample code) needs to be determined empirically; it depends on font (and judgment).