# Pseudo element first letter does not work

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a strange problem ::first-letter does not work on my web browser, but it does work on mobile screens.

```css
.navbar-brand::first-letter, .subscribe-form::first-letter, footer h4::first-letter {
    color: #a32424;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-auto navigation-desktop-home">
    <div class="logo-home">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-center w-100" href="/home.html">5test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does work on mobile and it does work for all other elements in css, but this .navbar-brand::first-letter does not work on larger screen. All browsers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:first-letter selector doesn't work for link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984179/first-letter-selector-doesnt-work-for-link)

Comment: Hi Lalji, I tried that, and unfortunately it does not work for me. The strange thing is that when I look at the mobile device, it does work :/ it only does not work on larger screen size

Comment: Check if the style is inside a media query or in a stylesheet that is loaded only on a mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::first-selector` doesn't work on inline elements, such as `a` tags.

### Make link inline-block

```css
.logo-home > .navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-brand::first-letter, .subscribe-form::first-letter, footer h4::first-letter {
    color: #a32424;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-auto navigation-desktop-home">
    <div class="logo-home">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-center w-100" href="/home.html">5test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Affect all children of by targeting parent .logo-home.

```css
.logo-home::first-letter {
    color: #a32424;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-auto navigation-desktop-home">
    <div class="logo-home">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-center w-100" href="/home.html">5test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the suggestion to make it an `inline-block` element. :) Are there any known drawbacks?

Comment: works perfectly with MAKE INLINE BLOCK. Thanks Rickard, accepted answer :)

Comment: @DusanKovacevic Please mark the post as the correct answer, otherwise people can't link to it when they mark other posts as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#first-letter). As of now, `inline` elements are not supported by `::first-letter`:

> In CSS, the `::first-letter` pseudo-element applies to block-like containers such as `block`, `list-item`, `table-cell`, `table-caption`, and `inline-block` elements.
> *Note: A future version of this specification may allow this pseudo-element to apply to more display types.*
> https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#application-in-css